# Visual Studio 2008: Change the font size of line number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration

Is there any way to hack visual studio so that it displays the line numbers in smaller font size like the way Notepad++ does?  I'm using Consolas at size 12 and the line numbers just look so ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Options... > Environment Fonts and Colors > Display Items > Line Numbers

You should be able to mess with fonts and sizes there.

**EDIT for the people whose hands need to be held:**

Follow this click path after you open Visual Studio 2008 (most likely by double-clicking on its icon):

Tools > Options... > Environment Fonts and Colors

"Tools" is in the menu bar at the top of the screen, and is most likely the fourth option from the right. Once you click on "Tools" a menu should come down, and you should click the "Options..." option, which is the very very last one. A new window will pop up with some junk on the right and some more things to click on on the left. Those things on the left determine what options you'll be setting on the right. Click the "Environment Fonts and Colors" option, which should be the second option.

Then, make sure "Show Settings For:" is set to "Text Editor". Click on "Line Numbers" in the listbox that says "Display Items". It is located underneath the "Font (bold type indicates fixed-width fonts):" dropdown box (that textbox with the arrow on the right side that when you click it, a whole bunch of options show up). It should be the 5th option in the "Display Items" box. After you do this, you can adjust your font, font size, color, whatever your little heart desires.

Once you're done, make sure to hit the "OK" button in the lower right corner of the window where you just made all your adjustments. Your new settings should be reflected!

:\

Comment: Does not look like I can change font sizes for individual items there.  When I change the size, everything else is changed to that size.

Comment: are you serious? did you even look? that's the exact path i took to change my line numbers.... thanks for the downvote :P

Comment: Jason -> That's not for Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Just tried this -- I can change the font size for Line Numbers -- but the change propagates to Plain Text as well.

Comment: oh it's not? that's funny, cuz that's all i use, and that's the path i took to get there. i could take 4 screen shots of my progression through the menus to find this. i can't believe that nobody else sees this, and that i'm STILL downvoted. lordy.

Comment: Exactly, I just can't find any way to make individual items in the display items to have different font sizes.  They can have different foreground, background colors.  But why not font sizes?

Comment: Are you saying that you can have line number at font size 9 and your code text (plain text) at font size 11 at the same time?

Comment: oh, well the font sizes themselves are all relative to each other. what if your line numbers were bigger than your text editor text? in order to have the line numbers remain meaningful, you'd have to space out the code lines, which kind of defeats the purpose. all text editor font is the same

Comment: "all text editor font is the same" is the actual answer here, if you're looking for an explanation of your downvotes (wasn't me if you're wondering)

Answer (score 3):

Even though Jason is correct in his directions, he even answered your question in a round about way.

> all text editor font is the same

when you have changed one of the font properties.

So in short. No you can not adjust individual fonts for items in the actual text editor, though you can adjust almost everything else through the Option dialog.

Hope this helps.